# How to return closest match for an array in Google Sheets Appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am struggling to return the highest count for a range of cells in A:A. The purpose of this code is to check for the value which is col A inside column N:N and return the highest character count in the sequences found. I am able to return the number of characters from the matched sequences just for A418 and any single cell, (can be A1). The issue is that I cannot get it to work for a range. In short I need to change A418 to a range such as this var dataA = sheet.getRange("A1:A1000").getValues();

```
function countCommonCharactersInOrder() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var searchString = sheet.getRange("A418").getValues().toString();
  var data = sheet.getRange("N:N").getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var text = data[i][0].toString();
    var commonCount = countCommonCharsInSequences(searchString, text);
    sheet.getRange(i + 1, 19).setValue(commonCount); // Column S (19th column)
  }
}

function countCommonCharsInSequences(str1, str2) {
  var commonCount = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
    var currentCommonCount = 0;
    
    for (var j = 0; j < str2.length; j++) {
      if (str1.charAt(i) === str2.charAt(j)) {
        currentCommonCount++;
        i++;
      } else {
        if (currentCommonCount > 2) {
          commonCount += currentCommonCount;
        }
        currentCommonCount = 0;
      }
    }
    
    if (currentCommonCount > 2) {
      commonCount += currentCommonCount;
    }
  }
  
  return commonCount;
}
```

Comment: In your showing script, it seems that the result value is put into column "S" by comparing a cell "A418" and cells "N:N". When you change a cell "A418" to "A1:A1000", what result do you want to obtain? Do you want to add 1000 columns from column "S"? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I am comparing the value in col A against the range in N:N. I am able to then return the highest count of characters in the sequencies found. Example  ```This is a boy and that is a girl``` vs a range which can be anything in N:N. One of the columns will have the closest resemblance e.g ```This is a boy and that is a boy```. It can get a bit complex this is a simple example. So in this example there is one sequence ```This is a boy and that is a ``` (23 characters). So if this is the highest we return 23. Now I need to use a range ```A1:A100``` instead of just ```A418```

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, you want to compare the cell values between "A1:A100" and "N:N", and you want to retrieve only one value of the maximum value from your function `countCommonCharsInSequences`. Do you want to also retrieve one of the values from "A1:A100" of the maximum value of the function? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Only the maximum in N:N for each row in Col A. So each of the row A:A will return its own maximum by checking in N:N

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected situation, I proposed an answer from your reply. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize. At that time, can you provide a sample value you expect? By this, I would like to modify the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your reply, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
function countCommonCharactersInOrder() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var searchString = sheet.getRange("A418").getValues().toString();
  var data = sheet.getRange("N:N").getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var text = data[i][0].toString();
    var commonCount = countCommonCharsInSequences(searchString, text);
    sheet.getRange(i + 1, 19).setValue(commonCount); // Column S (19th column)
  }
}
```

#### To:

```
function countCommonCharactersInOrder() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var dataA = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + lastRow).getValues();
  var data = sheet.getRange("N1:N" + lastRow).getValues();
  var res = dataA.map(([searchString]) => [Math.max(...data.map(([text]) => countCommonCharsInSequences(searchString, text)))]);
  sheet.getRange(1, 19, res.length).setValues(res); // Column S (19th column)
}
```

- By this modification, about each row of "A1:A", the maximum values from `countCommonCharsInSequences(searchString, text)` are put into coulmn "S".